# Saving on every change

Tags: ms-access, vba

Using Access VBA, In a form, I want to save every time a field changes. I'm guessing because I'm using some very complex queries, they don't always save immediately when they're dirty. `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` does the trick.

So my workaround is that every field has

```
Private Sub MyField_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End Sub
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I would say, not really. But the DoCmd seems redundant to the Me.Dirty method or vice versa. Shouldn't matter how complex queries are. Data is committed to table when 1) close table/query/form or 2) move to another record or 3) run code to save.

Answer (score 0):

The only piece of elegance I can add is changing the first line to `Me.Dirty = False`.

This is based on simple logic where if `Me.Dirty` is false, then the assignment doesn't change anything, but if `Me.Dirty` is true then you want to change it to false.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write out that code for every control. Just have one function:

```
Private Sub CommitChanges()
    If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End Sub
```

Then, for each control, instead of setting the after update event to `[Event Handler]`, set it to `=CommitChanges()`

Note, however, that I have a dislike for `DoCmd.RunCommand`. You could try:

```
Private Sub CommitChanges()
    If Me.Dirty And Me.Recordset.Updateable Then Me.Recordset.Update
End If
```